# Splitting uneven spaced column in Python

Tags: python, split

I tried to use the below program

```
import os

HOME= os.getcwd()

STORE_INFO_FILE = os.path.join(HOME,'storeInfo')  

def searchStr(STORE_INFO_FILE, storeId):
    with open (STORE_INFO_FILE, 'r') as storeInfoFile:
        for storeLine in storeInfoFile:
##          print storeLine.split(r'\s+')[0]
            if storeLine.split()[0] == storeId: 
                print storeLine

searchStr(STORE_INFO_FILE, 'Star001')
```

An example line in the file:

> Star001 Sunnyvale 9.00 USD Los_angeles/America sunnvaleStarb@startb.com

But it gives the below error

> ./searchStore.py  Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "./searchStore.py", line 21, in 
>       searchStr(STORE_INFO_FILE, 'Star001')   File "./searchStore.py", line 17, in searchStr
>       if storeLine.split()[0] == storeId:  IndexError: list index out of range

I have tried printing using split function on the command line and I was able to print it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you have an empty or blank line in your file:

```
>>> 'abc def hij\n'.split()
['abc', 'def', 'hij']
>>> '     \n'.split()    # a blank line containing white space
[]
>>> '\n'.split()         # an empty line
[]
```

The last 2 cases show that an empty list can be returned by `split()`. Trying to index that list raises an exception:

```
>>> '\n'.split()[0]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
IndexError: list index out of range
```

You can fix the problem by checking for empty and blank lines. Try this code:

```
def searchStr(store_info_file, store_id):
    with open (store_info_file) as f:
        for line in f:
            if line.strip() and (line.split()[0] == store_id): 
                print line
```

Adding `line.strip()` allows you to ignore empty lines and lines containing only whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Code has an issue if split method returns an empty list.
You can change code that calls split method and add error handling code.

Following can be done

```
storeLineWords = storeLine.split()
if len(storeLineWords) > 0 and storeLineWords[0] == storeId:
```